# React Router 4 rendering multiple layouts based on path?

Tags: reactjs, layout, react-router

Here's a very simple example I'm trying to work with.

```
export default class AppRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="website-wrapper">
        <Switch>
          <MainLayout>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          </MainLayout>
          <AnonLayout>
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
          </AnonLayout>
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Pretty straightforward but it's not functioning as you would expect

It's **always** rendering the `mainLayout` and only showing the content of `App` when the exact path is `/`.

`AnonLayout` and `NotFound` are never triggered at all.

I used to be able to do something similar in version 3, but this doesn't work with the latest version it's seems they changed how the routing works entirely in version 4 and the documentation has no mention of layouts and rendering layouts.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to do here, but if you don't want to put MainLayout inside your App component, you could do something like this:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => 
  <MainLayout>
    <App />
  </MainLayout>
/>
```

Comment: I want to render the `/` path with MainLayout, the `/login` path with AnonLayout. and have a fallback for not found.

It seems like with this I'll need to repeat `<MainLayout>` for every single path I need to render, isn't that too verbose?

Comment: Yep, you can do this for each route.